# "Could not find package" error when running javascript that uses elm

Tags: javascript, html, json, package, elm

I have javascript set up which uses elm-static-html-lib to generate html, and that requires passing in a view, model, and json decoder from my elm code.

When i try running the javascript using node, i get this error message: "Could not find package mdgriffith/style-elements."

The way I have the javascript set up is almost exactly how it's set up in the first example in the github page for elm-static-html-lib: https://github.com/eeue56/elm-static-html-lib

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

It seems like it's an issue with the method I'm using, because when I switch to using Html.program to create the view, I don't get any error with dependencies. And I've tried deleting elm-stuff/ and rebuilding, but it doesn't fix the issue.

Here is the JS code:

```
const esh = require("./node_modules/elm-static-html-lib/dist/index.js");
const fs = require('fs');
const model = { name: "Noah", age : 24 };
//const model = require('./index-new.json'); //with path
const options = { model : model, decoder: "Main.decodeModel", alreadyRun: false };


function generateHtml() {
    esh.default(process.cwd(), "Main.view", options)
    .then((generatedHtml) => {
        fs.writeFileSync("output.html", generatedHtml);
    });
}

generateHtml();
```

and my Main.elm module

```
module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (Html)
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Element exposing (..)
import Element.Attributes exposing (percent, width, spacing)
import Element.Events exposing (..)
import Style exposing (..)

-- MODEL


type alias Model =
    { age : Int
    , name : String
    }

type Style
    = None

type Variation
    = Selected

decodeModel : Json.Decode.Decoder Model
decodeModel =
    Json.Decode.map2 Model
        (Json.Decode.field "age" Json.Decode.int)
        (Json.Decode.field "name" Json.Decode.string)


-- VIEW


view : Model -> Element Style variation msg
view model =
  column None [] [text "Hello"]

stylesheet : StyleSheet Style Variation
stylesheet =
    Style.styleSheet
        [ style None [] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I investigated the elm-static-html-lib code and found out that it creates a directory named .elm-static-html and creates another elm-package.json based off of the current project's and puts it in that directory, so that that directory also has an elm-stuff folder. And for some reason, any package other than ones under elm-lang don't install even though they're listed in elm-package.json. At this point, I think I should talk to the creator of the library since it seems like it is a problem with his code.